# logrotate, permission error: others do not have write access, adding su user does not help

Tags: permissions, logrotate

I have a set of log files with the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 club club
```

and my custom logroate file looks like below:

```
/home/club/club/log/* {
        size 1M
        dateext
        dateformat .%Y%m%d-%s
        missingok
        rotate 1000
        compress
        notifempty
        create 0664 club club
        su club
}
```

but I get the error

```
error: error setting owner of /home/club/club/log/club.log.2019-04-05 to uid 1002 and gid 1002: Operation not permitted
```

How should I handle that? I was under the impression that by setting '`su club`' it would be able to do whatever it wants with the logfiles, what is missing here?

Comment: What if you remove `su club`? I don't really see a reason to use that here as the log rotation is usually run by root anyway, and you have a `create` statement that would recreate the log with an explicit owner and group.

Comment: it gets "error: skipping "/home/club/club/log/club.log.2019-07-13" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.", the parent directory /home/club/club/log/ has this permission: drwxrwxr-x  3 club club

Comment: Try replacing `create ...` by just `create`, as it then might not try doing the failing chown. With no args it is supposed to reproduce the old file's mode/user/group. Or perhaps use `nocreate` if your program will create it later. You should also consider replacing `*` by something that doesnt include the files that have already been rotated.

Comment: I changed it to /home/club/club/log/club.log.????-??-??{
        size 1M
        dateext
        dateformat .%Y%m%d-%s
        missingok
        rotate 1000
        compress
        notifempty
        su club
}, it renames the files, but cannot zip it , it says: error: error setting owner of /home/club/club/log/club.log.2018-10-03.20190720-1563645565.gz to uid 1002 and gid 1002: Operation not permitted

Comment: I did some testing and noticed my config works if I provide both user and group to su, with or without create, so try `su club club`.

Comment: Great, that works, why it had that weird behavior if I do not set the group in su?

Comment: Using `logrotate -v` provides some verbose output which shows it using group id of -1 if you dont provide a group. This might be the source of the problem, though group *nobody* is often -1.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `su` directive in logrotate config files, it's best practice to also specify the group.

> **su** *user* *group*

Failure to explicitly set the group can result in unexpected behavior.